# removing Objects from NSMutableArrays

Tags: ios, xcode, arrays

I have this method that gets called when i press a button and removes a Object from the MutableArray favs. Since it leaves holes in the Array I run into problems later. Is there an easy way to remove those "holes", or a better way to remove Objects?

```
- (IBAction)addfavs:(id)sender {

int erase;
for(int i=0;i<favs.count;i++){

    if ([favs objectAtIndex:i] == parent) {

        [favs removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        erase = 1;
    }
}
if (!erase) {
    [favs addObject:parent];
}
```

}

Comment: What type of problem did you run into?  btw: The if (!erase) ... might not work all the time.  Because erase can have a random number...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[EDIT4]**

Great point by user523234

```
[favs removeObjectIdenticalTo: parent];
```

Look at removeObjectIdenticalTo at Apples site for NSMutableArray

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html

**[EDIT3]**

Here is an example of checking with the value (using an integer value), instead of the object itself.

```
int erase = 0;
int i = 0;
while(i < favs.count){
    if ([[favs objectAtIndex:i] intValue] == [parent intValue]){
        [favs removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        erase = 1;
    }else{
        i++;
    }
}
```

**[EDIT2]**

The reason it may add an object even if it doesnt remove first is because you never reset your "erase" variable.  The first time you set it to 1, it is set for the rest of the time!!!  You also never initialize it, thus you never "really" know what the compiler is going to do with the variable the NEXT time your action is called.  If it "allocates" the same memory address to your erase variable the "1" will still be resident creating a static condition even though you havent defined it as a static variable!!!

**[EDIT]**

Didnt originally understand your question.  I think I understand now, taking a better look at your code.

Your Code:

```
int erase = 0; 
for(int i=0;i<favs.count;i++){
    if ([favs objectAtIndex:i] == parent){
        [favs removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        erase = 1;
    }
}
```

What you are doing essentially will SKIP certain items in the list as you increment your counter after each delete.  lets say that you remove object 3, your counter now will update to count 4, but 4 is now what was 5, and 3 is now what was 4, so you essentially are skipping item 4 in this case.

Try This:

```
int erase = 0;
int i = 0;
while(i < favs.count){
    if ([favs objectAtIndex:i] == parent){
        [favs removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        erase = 1;
    }else{
        i++;
    }
}
```

This will only upgrade the counter if you have NOT deleted the current item.

**[ORIGINAL]**
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Look at the removeObjectAtIndex method notes.

Direct from Apple:

"To fill the gap, all elements beyond index are moved by subtracting 1 from their index."

This should be being done automatically within Apple's API.  You should not have to do anything, and there really shouldnt be any "holes" left.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that, but the array should not have duplicate Objects anyway so thats not the problem. It still doesn't work correctly though. sometimes it will just skip the remove section and add an object anyway, thus creating duplicates and if called again only removing 1 of them even with your updated code...

Comment: What is parent then?  What are the objects within your array.  Also the reason it may just skip the remove section and add an object of type parent, is because you never reset your erase variable.

Comment: int erase = 0; at the beginning should reset it though.  parent is a NSNumber.

Comment: They are all NSNumber type (including the objects in the array)?  What kind of number within the NSNubmer class are you trying to use?  It may be better if you check the number instead of the object itself?  I will leave an example in my answer!!!

Answer (score 4):

When you remove an object from a mutable array, it doesn't "leave a hole".  Every other object in the mutable array just moves one notch down and the count (or length) of the array shrinks by the number of objects you've removed.

If you're seeing "holes" in your User Interface, you may be having trouble with your table view refresh methods or however else you're displaying the contents of the array.  But the base mutable array class definitely knows how to deal with removing and adding and managing its own objects.

Comment: I actually think if you read his code, his question is stated incorrectly.  I think his holes are an artifact of the WAY he is deleting, as he is potentially skipping items in the list every time he deletes an object!!!

Comment: gah... you're right.  +1 to you.  I'm bummed that the question wasn't worded in a way that I was able to help him get to right answer quicker.

Comment: LOL, right :-)  I have had this happen so many times because of language barrier, that it just make me laugh!!!

Answer (score 2):

Removing an object from an NSMutableArray does not leave holes. Apple's array implementation is not a sparse one, meaning the array is resized when you remove an object so that there are no blank spaces.

Comment: I actually think if you read his code, his question is stated incorrectly.  I think his holes are an artifact of the WAY he is deleting, as he is potentially skipping items in the list every time he deletes an object!!!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @trumpetlicks answer, you can also try this:
Edit: shorter version.

```
if ([favs containsObject:parent])  //check for present of parent in the favs
{
    [favs removeObjectIdenticalTo:parent];  //remove all occurrences of parent
} else
    [favs addObject:parent];
```

Comment: Actually even better is: [favs removeObjectIdenticalTo:parent]; If you look at the definition, it will remove "ALL" instances that are equal to parent!!!  +1